# $f '(x) = -f(x)$ and $f(1) = 1$, Solve for $f(2)$

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse

I am honestly not even sure how to start this problem... My first thought was that $f(2) = 2$ ... But now I don't even know where to go from there.

Comment: What function is of the same form as its derivative?  (Hint: try an exponential function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  What is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Ce^{-x}$, where $C$ is a real constant?

Comment: Would it be -Ce^-x ?

Comment: Yes.  So now all you have to do is use the initial condition to find the value of the constant $C$.

Comment: Would the answer be 2? And the original function would be f(x) = -ln e^-x ???

Comment: No.  $f(x)=Ce^{-x}$.  This results in $f'(x)=-f(x)$.  Now, since $f(1)=1$, that means that $f(1)=Ce^{-1}=1$.  Find the value of $C$ and use this to find $f(2)$.

Comment: Does C = e ????

Comment: Yes.  So $f(x)=e\cdot e^{-x}=e^{1-x}$.  Thus, $f(2)=e^{1-2}=e^{-1}$.

Comment: You're welcome.